# Find square matrices $A, B$, such that $\exp(A + B) \neq \exp(A) \exp(B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-calculus

The question is as the Title stated:

I picked a very easy example. However, I am afraid, I am missing something.

The two matrices that I picked are 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad 
B =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

My reasoning is that 
$$
\exp(A) = \begin{bmatrix}e^1& 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\exp(B) =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\exp(A)\exp(B) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$exp(A+B) = \begin{bmatrix} e^1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Please check it for me

Comment: You are not computing matrix exponential correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: I am sorry...the question should be finding an example to show that they are not equal

Comment: I just changed my example =, please take a look again.

Comment: $exp(A) = \begin{pmatrix}e&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $exp(B) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&e\end{pmatrix}$, so $exp(A+B) = \begin{pmatrix}e&0\\0&e\end{pmatrix}=exp(A)exp(B)$. Try taking $A$ and $B$ that don't commute.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf, the common theme to all the answers is that you don't take matrix exponentials by simply exponentiating each entry.  Your first step is to learn how; start with my link.  Only then are you ready to answer questions *about* matrix exponentiation.

Comment: Please do not change the question to the opposite after having received an answer. The answer is now useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0& 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad 
B =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
we have that
$A^2=A^k=0$, for all $k\ge 2$, and $B^k=B$, for all $k\ge 1$, and therefore
$$
\exp A=I +A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{A^n}{n!}+\cdots=I+A=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix},
$$ 
while
$$
\exp B=I +B+\frac{B^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{B^n}{n!}+\cdots=I+B+\frac{B}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{B}{n!}+
\cdots=I+(\mathrm{e}-1)B
=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \mathrm{e}\end{bmatrix}.$$
and
$$\exp(A)\exp(B) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & \mathrm{e}\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\exp(A+B) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \mathrm{e}-1 & \mathrm{e}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus your example WORKS!

**Note.** A characterization of the commutativity of the exponential of matrices is provided by:

**Theorem.** *Let $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tA}\mathrm{e}^{tB}=\mathrm{e}^{t(A+B)},
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb R$, if and only if $AB=BA$.*

For a proof Theorem 5 in these [notes](http://faculty.uml.edu/dklain/exponential.pdf).

Comment: @YiorgosSmyrlis you should maybe give a hint on how to prove your Theorem don't you think ?

Comment: I am sorry...the question should be finding an example to show that they are not equal

Comment: I just changed my example =, please take a look again.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: See update.

Comment: could you show me the process from A to exp(A) at the lower left entry: also could you show me how to calculate from (A+B) to exp(A+B) at the lower left entry?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: See new update.

Comment: how do you know $A^2=A^k=0$, for all $k\ge 2$, and $B^k=B$, for all $k\ge 1$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: Just calculate $A^2=A\cdot A$ and $B^2=B\cdot B$.

Comment: when i write it out, it make sense...i just did not write the the multiplication of two matrics...so i  was thinking how you can could so sure that, for example, the 67th matrix multiply the 68th matrix = 0....however, after writing it al out, it make senses ....thx a lot...you are very patient...